# Сложный запрос MySQL c GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

Не могу найти способ выбрать SELECTом такой результат:

```
id_item     name1       name2       name3
1           value10     value20     value30
2           -           value40     -
3           value50     value60     -
```

Из такой таблицы (Name - имя параметра для каждого id_item):

```
id_item     Name        Value
1           name1       value10
1           name2       value20
1           name3       value30
2           name2       value40
3           name1       value50
3           name2       value60
```

Существует ли способ?

*Вытаскивать всю таблицу как есть и обрабатывать в php - нельзя, ибо в этой таблице десятки тысяч строк, а по условию поставленной задачи php не может выбирать более 500 строк за раз из базы данных.

Если объеденить эту таблицу по id_item, строк получится всего несколько тысяч => запросы по 500 штук сработают сильно быстрее. Каждый из этих запросов станет несколько сложнее, но это несравнимо с выборкой десятков тысяч по 500.

Comment: Я правильно понял что id_item и цифра в Name меняются местами?

Comment: pivot погуглите, это очень похоже, если надо показать сделайте демку на sqlfiddle

Comment: Нет-нет, просто у каждого id_item есть некоторый список параметров (name1, name2, name3 ...). У некоторых  id_item могут совсем отстутствовать параметры, у некоторых их может быть полное количество ( в данном примере их три)

Comment: Посмотрите очень внимательно на приведённый вами пример, на параметры и их значения. Там точно всё правильно?

Comment: @mantigatos Простите пожалуйста, поспешил. Исправлено, теперь как должно быть

Comment: @eicto Сделал демку исходной таблицы: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9a252/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для решения вашей задачи необходимо воспользоваться динамическим формированием SQL запроса.

Запрос состоит из двух частей - первая часть формирует набор столбцов на основе уникальных значений name, затем выполняется запрос целиком.

```
SET @part_query = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('max(case when name = "', name, '" then value else "-" end) AS ', name)) INTO @part_query FROM example; -- Первая часть

SET @full_query = CONCAT('SELECT id, ', @part_query, ' FROM example GROUP BY id'); -- вторая часть

PREPARE stmt FROM @full_query; -- Выполнение сформированного запроса
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: Очень здорово! Спасибо огромное, действительно работает великолепно. Нигде не натыкался на такую магию :)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что такой способ на порядок производительнее чем обычная конкатенация names и values разделителем + конкатенация всех пар параметров другим разделителем, и дальнейшний двойной implode этого всего в php?

Comment: на порядок это громко сказано, к тому-же в том вопросе у вас массив создается, без нулевых значений...) тут вам придется их вычищать, либо тратить память php, так-что я думаю одинаково в итоге,  всё зависит от того что вы хотите добиться.

Comment: На самом деле нулевые значения мне как раз очень нужны - я их в тот массив вгонял отдельно, ибо если этого не сделать, произойдет смещение полей при записи в CSV файл, который является искомым результатом.

Comment: тогда это - в массив вообще не выбирайте, сразу на вывод подавайте выборку, вот это точно будет быстрее.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, так и сделаю